# How to display correct percentage on Y-axis using HighCharts js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm working with an area chart and I need to display this percentage on the Y-axis
[chart with (0%, 50%, 100%) on the Y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1goEx.png)

But in some cases my labels on the y-axis of the chart behave incorrectly. Maybe I can somehow set the values for the Y-axis labels myself?
[incorrect labels on the Y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fwV.png)

```
// this is the method from my angular component to get the Y-axis options
public getYAxisOptions(graphData: SeriesAreaOptions[]): YAxisOptions {
    const [allLeads] = graphData[0].data as number[];
    return {
        title: {text: null,},
        floor: 0,
        ceiling: allLeads || 100,
        min: 0,
        max: allLeads || 100,
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: (that: AxisLabelsFormatterContextObject<string>) => {
                if (allLeads) {
                    const percent = (Number(that.value) / allLeads * 100).toFixed(0);
                    return /*Number(percent) > 100 ? "" : `${percent}%`;*/  `${percent}%`;
                }
                return `${that.value}%`;
            }
        },
        gridLineDashStyle: "Dash",
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        lineWidth: 1,
        height: 130,
        top: 17,
        minRange: allLeads || 100
    };
}
```

UPD: this has already been resolved with tickPositions: [0, allLeads/2, allLeads]

Comment: Could you reproduce your attempt with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: I already resolved this issue with tickPositions, thanks